# Quel est le nom de la construction tautologique suivante : « Je vous dis au revoir ! »?

Tags: terminologie, linguistique, constructions

À la fin d'une conversation orale, il n'est pas rare que quelqu'un dise

> Et bien, je vous dis au revoir !

Bien que ce soit une construction courante, l'utilisation de « je vous dis » dans une phrase énoncée à l'oral est *tautologique* (ou *autoréférente*) du point de vue de la logique. Mais cette construction particulière porte-t-elle un nom ? Pouvez-vous donner d'autres exemples que « je te dis » ? Notamment, existe-t-il à l'écrit des formules similaires ?

Comment: Des constructions avec une redondance similaire (mais pas dans le même but) à l'écrit : « je vous signifie par la présente », « je porte à votre connaissance ».

Comment: Il va sans dire que

Comment: @mouviciel Celle-là est sublime, parce qu'en plus d'être performative, elle est contradictoire par construction. Mais c'est un idiome désormais, et son sens littéral n'est plus qu'un alibi...

Comment: En lisant la citation, j'ai ressenti une forme d'agression. Cette manière de se *redire* appelle a clore la discussion en mettant un point d'exclamation qui se veut *final*.

Comment: Personnellement, il m'arrive de dire et d'entendre "J'ai envie de dire : [quelque chose]", par exemple "Wahou, c'est super ce que tu as fait, franchement j'ai envie de te dire : bravo !". Je ne saurais vraiment expliquer pourquoi on utilise cette construction, peut-être pour appuyer la franchise de son propos : *j'ai envie de dire quelque chose et je ne me retiens pas de le dire*.

Comment: Quand j'apprenais les figures de style en cours de français, une m'avait marqué, c'est un peu le même principe. On dit quelque chose (souvent désagréable) tout en affirmant qu'on ne le dit pas. Ex : "Je n'oserais pas dire que vous êtes un idiot, mais ..." Edit : Comme mentionné plus bas, c'est une prétérition. Un cas particulier de ce que tu cherches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On appelle ce type d'usage [*expressions phatiques*](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Phatic_expression), en référence à la [fonction phatique](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Fonction_phatique) du langage. La référence en la matière est la description de [Jakobson](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Roman_Jakobson)

> Il y a des messages qui servent essentiellement à établir, prolonger, ou interrompre la communication, à vérifier que le circuit fonctionne ("Allô, vous m'entendez ?"), à attirer l'attention de l'interlocuteur ou à s'assurer qu'elle ne se relâche pas…
>   <sub>[Wikipédia:fr](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Fonction_phatique)</sub>

« Je vous dis » est un emploi du même type, de même que les « tu vois », « non ? », « hein ? », « si tu veux »… omniprésents à l'oral.

L'article [schéma de Jakobson](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Sch%C3%A9ma_de_Jakobson) donne plus de détails sur les fonctions du langage.

Comment: Je ne suis pas totalement convaincu. Dans la conversation « Pardon, que disais-tu ? Je disais que j'avais faim. » pas de problème, mais il me semble que dans certains cas comme celui du biblique « En vérité, je vous le déclare » il y a une certaine emphase qui sort du pur cadre phatique. C'est du phatique emphatique, en quelque sorte.

Comment: @Joubarc: Je pense que dans ce cas c'est plus une mesure d'atténuation de « au revoir », pour éviter de dire qu'on part, on dit qu'on le dit, pour ménager la face de ceux qu'on quitte (au sens de [Goffman](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Face_%28Erving_Goffman%29)). Ceci dit, ce n'est qu'une interprétation personnelle.

Comment: OK, mais donc ça sort aussi du phatique, même si ce n'est pas du tout dans le même sens. (Ca devient phatiquant d'essayer de comprendre tout ça)

Comment: @Joubarc: Disons que la fonction phatique est un canal de communication qui permet de mettre une emphase, ou de gérer une négociation. Dire que c'est une expression phatique ne suppose rien sur sa fonction dans l'interaction.

Comment: Could also be related to the explicit performatives of J.L. Austin and others: the utterance itself performs some action ("I swear" brings a vow into effect, "I pronounce you husband and wife" brings a marriage into effect, "I bet you" brings a wager into effect, and so on). Normally "Au revoir" is enough to end a conversation, but in this case is accompanied by an explicit statement of that fact... Anyway, I think phatic is a better analysis in this case, but this is another angle on it.

Answer (score 6):

Cette construction **n'est pas** tautologique !

Pour expliquer cette phrase de la forme **Je vous dis X**, deux voies d'explication n'ont pas encore été évoquées :

- D'une part, ça peut être une forme stylistique accentuant le propos par le moyen d'une redondance volontaire (*Et moi je vous dis que c'est impossible!*). On peut même y voir la forme canonique de l'*assertion*.

Mais surtout ceci :

- Cette montée d'un niveau vers le méta-langage est aussi la forme prise par de nombreux [**actes de langages**](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acte_de_langage), avec de nombreuses variantes comme *je déclare que*, *j'avoue que*, *j'affirme que*, etc. Ici, l'acte de langage concerné est la salutuation : *Je vous dis au revoir* n'apporte aucune information, mais accomplit un acte, celui de saluer avant de partir.

Comment: +1 Tautologique : Le Robert (2) Se dit de toute relation ou expression logique qui peut se réduire par analyse à une tautologie ; qui est toujours vrai. Affirmer que l'on prend la parole n'est pas lié à qui est dit : 'Je vous dis au revoir' ne peut pas être énoncé dans le même contexte relationnel que 'Au revoir' ou que 'Je vous dis' tout seul. Le faite de dire que l'on dit n'est pas équivalant au 'dit'

Comment: Précisément : l'énoncé n'est ni vrai ni faux! Il n'a de valeur que performative et non informative. On ne peut pas lui donner de valeur de vérité car il ne se situe pas dans le champ des énoncés falsifiables. L'acte de frapper mes deux mains l'une contre l'autre, lui non plus, n'est ni vrai, ni faux, c'est un acte.

Comment: Exactement, la phrase n'est pas une tautologie. Oui, c'est une phrase performative. Ce qui est dit coincide avec un acte.

Answer (score 5):

On pourrait dire que la *[prétérition](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9t%C3%A9rition)* est en quelque sorte la figure de style inverse.

> Je n'ai pas besoin de vous rappeler que vous me devez de l'argent.

Malheureusement, *prétérition* n'a [pas d'antonymes](http://www.cnrtl.fr/antonymie/pr%C3%A9t%C3%A9rition).

Pour d'autress exemples écrits de formules similaires à la sienne, il ne faut pas chercher plus loin que la Bible, avec ses « en vérité, je vous le déclare » à tour de page.

Peut-être une *[autoréférence](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autor%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence#En_linguistique)*, simplement?

Comment: Je vois la prétérition comme un cas particulier. On parle de quelque chose, et en le désignant, on le dit. Le fait qu'on dit que l'on va en parler ou non est un détail. "Je ne vous dit pas merci" n'est pas ne prétérition (il me semble) mais rentre bien dans la définition de la question (à mon sens)