# Is “ai” in "j'ai" and “finirai” pronounced exactly like “er” in infinitives?

Tags: prononciation, conjugaison

Is the *ai* in *j'ai* and *finirai* (I am assuming they are the same) pronounced exactly like the *-er* in infinitives: are *manger* and *mangeai* pronounced exactly the same?

Comment: I think "portager" is a uniquely Quebecois word, whereas I have no idea what the meaning of "porta j'ai" could be ("porta" doesn't even seem to be a French word). Perhaps it would be more helpful for your example to use standard, grammatically correct, forms.

Comment: I still think both questions ask "how do people pronounce the _-ai_ ending"; but they do this by presupposing different answers: like _-er_ (this question), or like _-ais_ (the other). No one seems to have issues with how to pronounce _-er_ or _-ais_ at all. (I think I made it clear enough, with the help of M. Pivot, that I believe _-ai_ should be like _-er_, so I'm not [going to repeat](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1101) it here). Anyway, for me, still duplicate.

Comment: @Dave: I would have liked to, but nothing grammatical came up, so I hoped people would just read the words aloud to themselves and assess their pronunciation. If *portager* is uniquely Quebecois, that might be a problem...

Comment: @Joubarc: I understand. I was taught in school to pronounce both digraphs exactly the same; but I was hoping there might be very subtle difference or something that might be revealed by reading words out loud (testing *portager* v. *porta j'ai* against a friend who should try to tell which one you're pronouncing, something like that). As it appears there is absolutely no difference at all, perhaps the question isn't interesting at all either. In any case, thanks for your answer.

Comment: On the contrary, considering the debate on how to pronounce _-ai_, I would say that the question is extremely interesting; it's just that the difficult point of it is the same as the other question. Keep in mind that while in my answer and opinion, _-ai_ should be pronounced the same way as _-er-_, not everyone seems to share that opinion.

Comment: Does he want a generic answer? In this case the answer is obviously no. If he wants regional discrepancies and exceptions then the answer is sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are the same 
[close-mid front unrounded vowel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) (`[e]`). Continuing [my own comparison](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/95) of *-ai* and *-ais* endings using the verb *grimper*, notice that *[grimper](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/grimper)* is listed as having the same pronunciation as [grimpé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/grimp%C3%A9). (Note that they use SAMPA symbols, not IPA.)

Please see the rest of my answer for an audio example of the pronunciation *-ai*. The third segment of the dictation also has various samples of the pronunciation of the *-er* ending (for example, *Ils se sont entraînés à en **déjouer** les pièges.*)

That said, it seems not everybody uses this pronunciation of *-ai* so the people who pronounce it like *-ais*<sup>1</sup> will indeed make a difference between *-ai* and *-er* (on which there is probably little discussion)

<sup>1. They're wrong :-)</sup>

Comment: That depends on the speaker. I pronounce *j'ai* like *jet* (`è` sound, open-mid vowel) and *mangeai* like *mangeais* (`è` again) and to rhyme with *mangerai* but *manger* with an `é` sound (close-mid vowel).

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add the "region-dependant" part. But I'm on Pivot's side.

Comment: petite précision : il est belge ! En France il y a une différence.

Comment: Pivot n'est pas Belge ;-)

Comment: Non le problème vient du son j (dans infligeai) précédent qui modifie légèrement la prononciation du è (vers le é). D'ailleurs ça marche également dans l'autre sens le j dans déjouer modifie le son é (vers le è). Si tu prends des exemples sans ce son genre "prendrai" (è) et "peler" (é) ça devient évident. **Cette réponse ne devrait pas être celle acceptée.**

Comment: @Knu alors, je te suggère de faire de ton commentaire une réponse, et d'y ajouter les références nécessaires. Et si tu as des exemples audio avec _prendrai_ (ou autres), je suis curieux de les entendre. (Si je suis bien, tu considères que la pronociation de la fin d'_infligeai_ diffère de celle de _prendrai_, c'est bien ça?)

Comment: Oui. Mais j'ai rien contre ta prononciation je dis juste qu'il vaudrait mieux que la réponse choisie soit celle qui correspond au français métropolitain. Si tu ne fais pas la distinction entre *prendrai* et *peler* il est clair que tu seras incapable d'imaginer la nuance entre *infligeai* et *prendrai*.

Comment: En effet, je considère que _[prendrai](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/prendrai)_, _[peler](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/peler)_, et _[ingligeai](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/infligeai)_ utilisent tous le même son `[e]`. C'est peut-être dû à mon accent, mais je remarque quand même que l'ATILF est du même avis (suivre les liens). Il ne m'appartient pas d'accepter une réponse, et je vois mal pourquoi je passerais mon temps à prétendre que ma réponse ne devrait pas être acceptée. Et pourquoi, si cette réponse est trop régionale, n'y a-t-il pas 10 autres réponses « métropolitaines » ?

Comment: Je ne t'ai pas -1 t'inquiète mais il est clair pour moi que la majorité des visiteurs préféreraient avoir la réponse correspondant au français le plus répandu sélectionnée même si l'autre est plus courte et moins détaillée.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's a slight difference in pronunciation between the  two forms (although some people in france can't pronounce it differently) :

mangerai *(will eat)* is pronounced [ɛ] while manger *(to eat)* is pronounced [e].

Comment: @Evpok - I think he just pronounces things differently. I'd use `[e]` for both anyway.

Comment: I've never heard `[ɛ]` (the `è` sound) for an infinitive.

Comment: Me neither, but then again, I've never heard it for a simple past.

Comment: @Joubarc, I've heard people who don't seem to make a difference between `[ɛ]` and `[e]`, but with Gilles description of his own pronunciation I wonder if I'm not mistaken. There is an underlying question here and I'll ask it when I've time to spell it out.

Comment: Wow! If native French-speakers can't agree between themselves, what hope is there for the rest of us? :)

Comment: @Benjol: None. You are doomed.

Comment: @Benjol: when your only hope is to start learning Dutch, you know you are doomed indeed.