# Les sons : [ε] vs [e] (parlais vs parlai)

Tags: prononciation

Lors de la **conjugaison**, p. ex.

> Vous avez [ave] vs j'avais [avε]
>
> J'aurai [o.ʁe] vs j'aurais [o.ʁɛ]
>
> J'offrirai vs j'offrirais

etc., fait-on de nos jours une vraie différence entre les sons [e] et [ε] ?

Comment: Un sujet récurrent: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1202/variations-sur-lutilisation-de-e-et-%C9%9B?rq=1 https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11652/pourquoi-le-fran%C3%A7ais-parisien-a-t-il-perdu-pour-la-plupart-la-distinction-entre?rq=1 https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29959/is-allait-pronounced-ale-or-al%C9%9B?noredirect=1&lq=1 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les trois cas sont différents, et pour chaque cas l'opposition existe dans certains dialectes et pas dans d'autres.

> Vous avez [ave] vs j'avais [avε]

Des trois, c'est la stable des oppositions. Elle se fait partout où les /e/ et les /ε/ sont distingués en finale de mot, ce qui comprend toujours une majorité des francophones. Dans le Midi de la France et dans certaines ex-colonies françaises, les deux phonèmes se confondent en /e/ en fin de mot, y-compris les verbes à l'imparfait et au conditionnel.

> J'aurai [o.ʁe] vs j'aurais [o.ʁɛ]

En France, les deux suffixes tendent à se confondre, par deux processus différents: dans le Midi, la même absence d'opposition entre  /e/ et /ε/ fait que les deux suffixes se prononcent /ʁe/; tandis que dans la partie nord, l'effet ouvrant du /ʁ/ et une tendance à interpreter la graphie ⟨ai⟩ comme représentant toujours /ε/ font que les deux suffixes se confondent en /ʁɛ/.

Hors de la France, l'opposition est par contre toujours bien marquée en Amérique, dans la grande majorité de la Belgique et dans la partie nord de la Suisse Romande.

Pour le français européen, l'enquête (basée sur un questionnaire et les réponses volontaires des répondants) du site [Français de nos Régions](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2018/02/25/6999/) a permis de produire une carte de cette opposition, sans toutefois indiquer si la fusion des suffixes s'est faite en faveur de /ʁɛ/ ou de /ʁe/:

[image]

> (parlais vs parlai) (dans le titre initial de cette question)

Le passé simple étant défunt et son apprentissage du ressort de l'école primaire, la prononciation du suffixe -ai dépend largement de la formation des enseignants et de la transmission qu'ils en font à leurs élèves. Une telle prononciation artificielle n'a cependant pas beaucoup d'intérêt pour les linguistes et je ne connais aucune enquête récente sur les habitudes de prononciation de la première personne du passé simple.

Même en grandissant dans une région qui distingue bien -rai et -rais (et j'ai de il est), on ne m'a jamais appris à prononcer "je mangeai" différemment de "je mangeais".

Answer (score 1):

La différence est techniquement encore d'actualité de nos jours, mais bien souvent, selon le zone géographique et les accents de langage, les deux sons sont prononcés de la même façon.

This difference in pronunciation is technically still there, but in fact, depending on the area and accent, both sounds are often pronounced the same.