# Variations sur l'utilisation de [e] et [ɛ]

Tags: prononciation, régionalismes, accents-régionaux, voyelles

On a remarqué la [richesse en voyelles du français](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/887/176).  Mais il est bien connu que certains accents perdent certaines des différences. Je ne fais pas la différence entre [ɑ] et [a].  D'autres m'agacent en ne le faisant pas entre [œ̃] et [ɛ̃] tandis que l'absence de différence entre [o] et [ɔ] ne me gène pas même si je la fais moi-même.

Je savais que j'utilisais [ɛ] à la place de [e] dans certains contextes tout en gardant [e] dans d'autres.  Mais [deux](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1119/176) [questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1101) m'ont fait remarquer que certains font la substitution suivant d'autres règles que les miennes (que je serais incapable de définir, la section de [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais) sur la Belgique indique « syllabes ouvertes atones » et décrit assez bien en général ma prononciation). De plus
[Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais) donne l'impression que la différence entre [e] et [ɛ] se perdait aussi complètement parfois, mais je ne suis pas sûr d'avoir jamais entendu un tel dialecte.

1. Est-ce qu'il y a réellement des dialectes qui ne font pas la différence ?  Que prononcent ces locuteurs ? [e], [ɛ] ou un son intermédiaire que mon oreille interpréterait comme celui qu'elle attend ?
2. Est-ce qu'il y a des dialectes qui prononcent [e] quand le français standard attend [ɛ] ?
3. Est-ce qu'il y a réellement des règles de substitutions (et quelles sont elles) ou bien celles-ci ne sont déterminées que par des usages ?

Comment: « D'autres m'agacent en ne le faisant pas entre [œ̃] et [ɛ̃] » Tu dois être souvent agacé, non ?

Comment: Je suis dans une région où la différence se fait.

Comment: @JPP Effectivement cette distinction a tendance à se perdre (je prononce moi-même [œ̃] comme [ɛ̃]) !

Comment: Comment peut-on prononcer deux sons si lointains de la même manière ? !

Comment: \[œ̃\] et \[ɛ̃\] sonnent pour moi presque à l'identique, je n'arrive tout simplement pas à prononcer \[œ̃\] et n'utilise que l'autre. De même si certains prononcent les deux distinctement, je dois y être sourd car j'avoue ne pas l'entendre. Inversement, comme Elena, je trouve \[ɛ\] et \[e\] très différents et j'ai du mal à concevoir qu'on les confonde. Simple témoignage.

Comment: @RomainVALERI, l'oreille n'entends que les différences auxquelles elle est éduquées.  J'ai travaillé avec des africains qui ne faisait pas la différence entre L et R (et eu quelques quiproquo car Roland et Laurent, c’était du pareil au même pour eux), tout comme moi je n'arrivais pas à faire la différence entre les tons dans leur langue (causant aussi quelques éclats de rire). _Brun_ et _brin_ sont clairement différent pour moi.

Comment: Il y a une carte pour la prononciation à la finale en France ici: https://francaisdenosregions.com/2017/07/06/ces-mots-qui-ne-se-prononcent-pas-de-la-meme-facon-dun-bout-a-lautre-de-la-france/.

Answer (score 3):

Je n'ai pas de réponse à toutes les questions, mais je sais qu'en tant que Lorrain, et en tant que chanteur, j'ai dû revoir la prononciation de « les » et « des » (par exemple). Chez nous on dit [le] et [de] là où il semblerait que le français « académique » (ou au moins la façon académique de le chanter) dise [lɛ] et [dɛ]. Donc pour la question 2, il semble que oui.

Comment: Je prononce [lɛ], mais la page de Wikipedia a l'air de dire que c'est une caractéristique belge.

Answer (score 3):

Si ma mémoire est bonne, en français standard `[e]` et `[ɛ]` sont des variantes libres du phonème `/e/`, sauf à la finale, et encore les seules paires minimales sont marée~marais et dé~dais qui ne sont pas d'un usage très courant.

Donc en théorie on peut presque toujours remplacer l'un par l'autre et je le vérifie assez bien en pratique. À peu près tous le monde fait naturellement des substitutions selon le contexte. Ce n'est donc pas tant qu'il y ait un son intermédiaire, mais plutôt que la distinction n'a plus de sens.

Comment: J'ai au moins comme paires minimales supplémentaires toute le futur et le conditionnel, le passé simple et l'imparfait (et l'infinitif des verbes en -er), lez (qui se trouvait dans le nom d'une commune que j'ai habité) et les, fée et fait, dé et des, j'arrête de chercher.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Non. En ce qui concerne les verbes, premièrement d'autres questions récentes montrent que la différence perçue entre *er* et *ai* par exemple n'est pas évidente. Ensuite ce ne sont pas des paires minimales au sens strict, puisque ce ne sont pas des verbes au mêmes temps, modes, personnes et aspect. Pour *fée* et *fait*, il est courant d'entendre *fait* prononcé `[fe]`. Et même si c'étaient des vraies paires minimales ça ne concernerait de toute façon que les finales.

Comment: @evpok La prononciation de *fait* peut parfois varier par exemple lorsqu'il y a une répétition : "j'ai fait faire" là on opte plutôt pour fé (au lieu de fè habituellement). En gros le contexte joue un rôle dans la prononciation.

Comment: @Knu C'est bien ce que je voulais dire.

Comment: Aussi peut-être *foret* et *forêt* ? En tout cas, par chez moi (sud-ouest) on a horreur des [ɛ] finaux, et on prononce absolument toujours [e] à la fin des mots (mais pas au milieu, comme dans *crêpe* par exemple).

Answer (score 2):

> Est-ce qu'il y a réellement des dialectes qui ne font pas la différence ? Que prononcent ces locuteurs ? [e], [ɛ] ou un son intermédiaire que mon oreille interpréterait comme celui qu'elle attend ?

À mon oreille de canadien-français, la majorité des locuteurs originaires de France ne semblent pas faire la différence et tout assimiler à [ɛ], ce qui rend parfois la différence entre le futur et le conditionnel ambiguë.

> Est-ce qu'il y a réellement des règles de substitutions (et quelles sont elles) ou bien celles-ci ne sont déterminées que par des usages ?

D'un point de vue strictement linguistique, il y a sûrement des règles, mais elles ne seront pas les mêmes partout, et ça prendrait des linguistes spécialisés dans chacun des divers dialectes de la francophonie pour départager tout ça! En tant que principe, c'est le même phénomène qui a fait que les mêmes mots latins se soit transformés de façon différente dans les diverses langues romanes -- différentes régions on appliqué différentes règles de substitution pour des sons à l'origine identiques, mais à un niveau moins prononcé.

Comment: Parfois notre oreille de canadiens-français pourrait perdre une subtilité qui n'échapperait pas à un auditeur local. J'ai lu que certains Français, dans une région particulière, allongeaient leurs nasales en fin de mots **lorsque ces mots sont au pluriel** (lapin /lapɛ̃/, lapins /lapɛ̃ː/). Bien qu'objectivement l'allongement y soit, il pourrait fort bien échapper à tous ceux (fort nombreux) qui ne pratiquent pas cette façon de marquer le pluriel.

Comment: Aussi, les Belges ont le couple A bref/A long pour marquer ce qu'au Québec on distingue avec /a/ et /ɑ/. Un canadien-français non averti dirait que la distinction ne se fait pas chez les Belges.

Comment: Fascinant ce concept d'allonger les nasales au pluriel. Je n'en avais jamais entendu parler, mais je suis d'accord que cette distinction, tout comme celle du A bref/A long des Belges, va échapper à l'oreille de tout auditeur dont le dialecte ne contient pas la distinction.

Comment: Je crois que j'avais vu ces informations dans _[Le français dans tous les sens](http://www.laffont.fr/site/le_francais_dans_tous_les_sens_&100&9782221124116.html)_ d'Henriette Walter, si vous êtes intéressé.

Comment: Merci pour la référence. Dommage pour moi que vivre au Japon ne me permette pas d'aller feuilleter l'ouvrage en librairie ou en bibliothèque!

Comment: Un jour on repasse au pays ou les gens du pays passent nous voir. J'ai aussi vécu plus d'une décennie hors du Québec, je connais la ‘misère’ de trouver un titre en un lieu où le français est une langue exotique.

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a pas d'accent qui « confonde » [e] et [ɛ] (il n'y en a pas non plus qui ne fasse pas la différence entre [o] et [ɔ]), il y a simplement des régions où s'applique mieux que dans d'autres ce qu'on appelle « loi de position », qui dit qu'une voyelle est fermée en syllabe ouverte et ouverte en syllabe fermée.

L'accent qui correspond au « français standard » (car c'est bien un accent) n'applique pas toujours cette loi de position, donc bien sûr que certains accents prononcent [e] là ou d'autres prononcent [ɛ], et réciproquement.

Par exemple, l'accent prétendument standard prononce « les » avec un [ɛ] là où la loi de position voudrait un [e]. Je ne saurais dire pourquoi l'accent standard opère une telle substitution.

Comment: J'ai ici sur mes genoux _Le Robert méthodique_ en sa version 1990. On y déclare que _J'arrivai_ se prononce identiquement à _J'arrivais_ et que _J'arriverai_ est un homophone de _J'arriverais_... S'il n'existe pas d'accent qui confonde les deux, pourquoi un éditeur comme Le Robert se commettrait-il à prendre position pour un fait linguistique inexistant?

Comment: Parce que le simple fait qu'on prononce « j'arriverai » et « j'arriverais » tous les deux avec un [e] n'implique pas qu'on n'utilise pas [ɛ] dans d'autres mots.

Comment: Ça va dans l'autre direction (on propose [ɛ] pour les quatre cas), mais c'est de peu d'importance. Le fait est qu'un phonème peut avoir différentes formes. Si l'utilisation de l'une pour l'autre est systématiquement indifférente, alors il s'agit d'un seul phonème et non de deux. Il y a alors confusion non parce que l'oreille ou l'appareil vocal ne différencie pas, mais parce que le cerveau ne différencie pas. Au Québec, on prononce _enfant_ /ɑ̃fã/. Toute autre prononciation laisse paraître un accent, mais le cerveau confond bien les deux sons et les traite comme le même élément linguistique.

Comment: Un autre exemple québécois qui illustre bien à quel point l'une et l'autre prononciation du son «en» est indifférente par rapport au sens interprété: _cent_ se dit /sã/, mais _cent ans_ si dit /sɑ̃tã

Comment: Bien sûr qu'il s'agit d'un seul phonème dans le cas de ces mots prononcés ainsi, mais le deuxième phonème continue à exister quand même. Ça n'a rien à voir avec le cas de [œ̃] et [ɛ̃] : là les deux sont bien confondus, ils ne forment plus qu'un seul son quel que soit le mot et quelle que soit la place dans le mot.

Comment: Juste pour être certain: son ≠ phonème. Un phonème se distingue d'un autre par une certaine qualité phonétique, mais peut recouvrir une certaine plage de sons différents sans pour autant devenir plusieurs phonèmes.

Comment: Oui, je me suis trompé, j'ai voulu dire « le deuxième son continue à exister ».

Comment: Nous sommes bien d'accord. [e] & [ɛ] peuvent bien continuer d'exister sans pour autant être des phonèmes distincts. Leur position dans un mot ou dans la chaîne parlée suffira à justifier que l'on emploie l'un pour l'autre, sans signification particulière. La variante /ɪ/ du phonème [i] au Québec en est un exemple: elle ne servira pas, comme en anglais, à différencier deux mots (bit/beat). La variante ne sera que la prononciation du phonème en dernière syllabe d'un mot, lorsque suivi d'une consonne. Les R roulés ou grasseillés sont un autre exemple de variation d'un phonème, régionale celle-ci.

Comment: D'accord, seulement la question d'origine n'est pas de savoir s'il y a deux phonèmes distincts, mais si les sons [e] et [ɛ] sont confondus en un seul son (comme c'est effectivement le cas pour [œ̃] et [ɛ̃]).

Comment: J'avais cru comprendre que l'un impliquait l'autre, à savoir que l'indifférence d'interprétation provoque un type de variation qui n'a plus rien à voir avec l'utilisation habituelle des deux phonèmes, mais avec autre chose (par exemple la différence de positionnement du son dans la chaîne parlée, plutôt que la signification du mot). Vous me prenez un peu de court et je dois admettre que je me suis un peu laissé emporter sur le sujet, je m'en excuse. Il demeure que l'exemple du _Robert méthodique_ me laisse croire que la distinction pourrait exister quelque part.