# When to put an accent on the letter E

Tags: prononciation, diacritiques, rule-of-thumb

I've encountered the rule on writing accents:

- When at the end of a syllable and not at the end of a word, a vowel gets an accent.

Examples:

> épître (é-pî-tre) ;
>   pénétrer (pé-né-trer) ;
>   été (é-té) ;
>   célèbre (cé-lè-bre)

But also there are the same cases (end of a syllable) where accent is not set and ‘*e* muet’ is pronounced

Examples:

> secret (se-cret) ;
>   petit (pe-tit) ;
>   fenêtre (fe-nê-tre) ;
>   samedi (sa-me-di) ;
>   leçon (le-çon)

What is the general rule that governs accent writing for *e* and ‘*e* muet‘?

Comment: actually those grave and acute accents indicate how to pronounce the word, they are not there because of a rule : f*e*nêtre : `ø`, p*é*nétrer : `e`.

Comment: ok, does it need to memorize the spelling of all the French words then? if there is no rule to govern when to set accent?

Comment: Il parle de préconceptions ou de véritables règles?

Comment: What is an *e muet* ? How many *e muets* in *revenu* ? Which ones?

Comment: @Chesnokov Yuriy: yes, you need to memorize accents, they are part of the word and convey sense.

Comment: I wonder if _accent_ isn't used here with the meaning of _stress_ instead of _diacritic mark_. But for most practical purpose French has no stress.

Comment: Could you indicate where you encountered that rule ? (If it was in a shady bar, maybe she was lying about being a rule at all)

Comment: @mouviciel in revenu all e are e muet

Comment: @Joubarc in a book on French language, it is not in English. They report the rule to facilitate understanding based on Timonhe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, note that French spelling is primarily based on pronunciation, but secondarily based on etymology. There are many words for which the pronunciation allows many different spellings, and the choice of an actual spelling reflects the word's etymology. For example, most silent letters reflect a sound that existed in Old French or Latin.

I think I see what rule you're thinking of. It's easier to understand if you look at how to go from the spelling to the pronunciation rather than the other way round.

First, if the letter `e` has an accent, it dictates the pronunciation: `é` is always¹ pronounced with the half-closed sound [`/e/`](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_moyenne_sup%C3%A9rieure_ant%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie) while `è` and `ê` are pronounced with the half-open sound [`/ɛ/`](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_moyenne_inf%C3%A9rieure_ant%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie). For the unadorned letter `e`, there are three cases (which have a few exceptions):

- At the end of a syllable, `e` is pronounced [`/ə/`](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_moyenne_centrale); this sound is unstressed and often omitted in speech (more or less often depending on how hard it is to pronounce the resulting sequence of consonants). If the `e` is not sounded, then any preceding consonant is thrown into the preceding syllable. Examples: *s**e**cret* `/sə.kʁɛ/`, *sam**e**di* `/sam.di/` or `/sa.mə.di/`.
  At the end of a word², `e` is almost always not sounded (“e muet”) in most dialects of French.
- When there is a subsequent consonant in the syllable, `e` is pronounced [`/ɛ/`](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_moyenne_inf%C3%A9rieure_ant%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie). Common cases are `e` followed by a double consonant, and `e` followed by a single consonant at the end of a word when the consonant is sounded. Examples: *b**e**lle* `/bɛl/`, *s**e**c* `/sɛk/`, *s**e**cteur* /sɛktœʁ/.
- Words ending in `-et` are pronounced `/ɛ/`, and words ending in `-er` are pronounced `/e/`. Examples: *secr**e**t* `/sə.kʁɛ/`, *parl**e**r* `/paʁ.le/`.
  Note that single-syllable words ending in `-er` usually sound the `r` (and by the rule above the `e` is pronounced with an open sound): *cher* `/ʃɛʁ/`, *mer* `/mɛʁ/`.
  Single-syllable articles ending in `-es` have a pronunciation that [varies between `[e]` and `[ɛ]`](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1202/variations-sur-lutilisation-de-e-et) depending on the sentence and the speaker: *ces*, *des*, *les*, *mes*, *tes*.

Note that the rules above, in addition to having exceptions, do not give a complete key to the pronunciation of a word because you need to know where to break up the syllables.

To go from pronunciation to spelling: `/ə/` is spelled `e` and `/e/` is spelled `é` (except in the `-er` final). As for the open sound `/ɛ/`:

- If there is a subsequent consonant in the same syllable, then an unadorned `e` is pronounced `/ɛ/` already, and therefore the word is spelled without an accent. Examples: *b**e**lle* `/bɛl/`, *s**e**c* `/sɛk/`, *s**e**cteur* /sɛktœʁ/.
- If there used to be a subsequent consonant but that consonant disappeared at some point in Old French, then the consonant is replaced by circumflex mark. The consonant is usually an `s`, and there are often related words that have kept the `s`. Examples: *être* (distantly related to *essence*), *fête* (related to *festival*), *forêt* (related to *forestier*).
- Otherwise the spelling is `è` (grave accent), though sometimes `ê` is used for purely arbitrary reasons.

Note that the sounds `/e/` and `/ɛ/` can also be written `-ai-`. This is purely based on etymology: `-ai-` derives from a root that had both `a` and `i`, usually separated by a consonant that was eroded but may still be found in related words. For example, *faire* comes from the Latin *facio* (related to *factuel*, from a pre-Latin root *taci(t)-*), *maire* (from *maior*), *taire* (from *tacio*, related to *taciturne*). Etymology can be tricky to trace sometimes, due to the way different words evolved at different times and in different directions: constrast *[chair](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cher)* from *carnis* (now associated with the root `carn-`) with *[cher](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cher)* from *carus* (related to *caritas*, with an `i` still present in French words like *charité* and *caritatif*).

¹  <sub>Well, almost always.</sub> 
²  <sub>Or when the `e` is followed by a silent letter: mainly this covers words ending in `-es`, and there is also `-ent` in the specific case of a third person plural conjugated verb.</sub> 
³  <sub>As opposed to *mer*, related to *maritime*, where it's the `a` alone that became `e` and not `a` plus a following consonant.</sub>

Comment: thank you very much for extensive reply, let me have some time to digest it

Comment: It is mildly counter-intuitive to have silent letters in 'spelling which is primarily based on pronunciation' :)

Comment: Note that when "re" is prefixed to a word beginning with "s" (most often to indicate that the action is reiterated), an additional "s" is inserted so that the sound is /s/, not /z/; however, the "e" is pronounced /ə/, not /e/] or /ɛ/. Examples: "ressembler", "ressaisir". Note also that, while "dessert" is prononced /de.sɛʁ/, "ressac" is pronounced /ʁə.sak/.