# Utilisation des accents grave et aigu sur la lettre e

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, phonétique, diacritiques

Je voudrais savoir pourquoi dans certains mots on écrit la lettre `e` avec un accent grave `è`, bien qu'on prononce le mot avec un accent aigu `é`.

À titre d'exemple je peux citer :

- *très*
- *près*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pour ce qui est de "près" et de "très", on utilise la prononciation usuelle du "è". Pour ce qui est d'autres termes, c'est l'usage, donc une règle bête et méchante. En revanche, certains régionalismes ont tendance à changer certaines prononciations (les "é" deviennent "è" ou inversement", un "o" fermé devient un "o" ouvert...) et il n'y a pour cela aucune règle.

Comment: Pour moi, je n'ai jamais entendu le mot très prononcé avec un accent grave.Si j'ai compris les mots proches de très et près échappent à la règle

Comment: ... Quelle règle ?

Comment: celle la ` donc une règle bête et méchante`

Comment: Ah. Je pense que tu as compris à l'envers : tous les mots ayant un accent aigu doivent avoir une prononciation usuelle en "è", y compris "très" et "près". Ce sont les exceptions qui sont à retenir, même si aucune ne me vient spontanément à l'esprit.

Answer (score 2):

Il y a pas mal de variations dans l'utilisation de [e] et [ε], en fonction du contexte et des accents.  D'aucuns ont pu même dire que *[[e] et [ɛ] sont des variantes libres du phonème /e/, sauf à la finale](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1204/176)*.

Quant à *très* et *près*, les voyelles sont en position finales.  Mais la prononciation que j'utilise (en accord avec les dictionnaires que j'ai consultés), c'est [tʀε] et [pʀε]. [pʀe] existe bien, mais c'est la prononciation de *pré*.

Answer (score 0):

En français, les accents grave, aigu et circonflexe font d'abord partie de l'orthographe. Ils n'ont qu'un lien indirect avec la prononciation, elle-même liée aux particularités régionales.

Le deuxième *é* de *événement*, le *è* de *règle*, le deuxième *e* de *envers* et le *ê* de *même* peuvent ainsi se prononcer de façon identique.

Comment: La graphie de évènement a été corrigée. La graphie avec deux accents aigus était apparemment dû à une erreur d'imprimerie. ([source](https://www.rtl.fr/culture/arts-spectacles/evenement-l-histoire-de-ce-deuxieme-accent-aigu-qui-derange-7789934426) qui vaut ce qu'elle vaut)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat: La nouvelle orthographe n'a pas fait perdre sa validité à l'ancienne.